# IOS testing: Test interaction between two apps

Tags: ios, testing, instruments, appium

I need to automate a test on an IOS app using UI automation.
I need to test the following scenario.

1) open the mail app and select a file to share. This will open my app
2) Now I need to perform UI actions on my app and do some tests

I can't figure out how do automate this scenario using Instruments or Appium. All these tools take bundle name of one app. I need a way to control and perform UI actions on two app from a single script.

Any suggestions?

Edit: For clarification

Comment: Run one app, send the file. Close the app open the second and see if you got it. Does it get more complicated?

Comment: @CaptJak  In Instruments I can only give one bundle name as the target. So in one script I am not able to control two apps.  To do what you are suggesting, I will have to run two scripts in sequence.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need instruments?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question. I am doing UI automation using Instruments.

Comment: I really do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your question and include what you are trying to do. Why are you using UI Automation?

Comment: You don't need to use UIAutomation. Just use the simulator

Comment: @CaptJak I need to automate these tests, not just execute it once.

Comment: I still don't understand. When you ask a question, you need to put all of the data in the question. Based off of what you have written, the simulator should be a good enough tool.

Comment: @CaptJaK, May be I am missing something. Are you saying that I can *automate* the scenario I have described in simulator without using instruments? Can you describe how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

[This is not possible within one session](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-platform-support)

The solution is to split up your tests to encompass one or more webdriver sessions.

**Part One:**

```
desired_caps['app'] = 'sampleApp1'
driver = webdriver.new('http://0.0.0.0/wd/hub:4732', desired_caps)
// Do what you need to do.
driver.quit()
```

**Part Two:**

```
desired_caps['app'] = 'sampleApp2'
driver = webdriver.new('http://0.0.0.0/wd/hub:4732', desired_caps)
// Do what you need to do.
driver.quit()
```